# How to stream JSON request in Hapijs?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have a really big JSON request, which is causing 413 error. I was exploring what could be the workaround to solve this issue(other than increasing the request size) and found streaming as an option. However, I couldn't find any example for streaming JSON requests. How can I do that? Below is my code

```
this.server.route({
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/vov',
            config: {
                payload: {
                    output: 'stream',
                    allow: ['application/json','multipart/form-data'] 
                },
                handler: (request, reply) => {

                    // request.setEncoding('utf8');
                    let payload = request.payload;
                    this.onMessage(payload);
                    // payload.on('data', (chunk) =>{
                    //     console.log(chunk);
                    //     // this.onMessage(payload);
                    //     // setTimeout(() => {return reply.continue()},30000);
                    // });
                    // payload.on('end', (chunk) =>{
                    //     console.log(chunk);
                    //     this.onMessage(payload);
                    //     setTimeout(() => {return reply.continue()},30000);
                    // });

                    // return reply.continue();
                }

            }

        });
```

Comment: Where do you get the json from ?

Comment: Client makes a HTTP request

Comment: You mean,  you receive a big json file

Comment: No, it's a big JSON request with header application/json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the `false` to payload:

```
payload: {
    output: 'stream',
    parse: false
}
```

This will return the stream unmodified in payload. 
Then you can use the [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream) module to process the big stream file.

```
const payload = request.payload;
payload.pipe(JSONStream.parse(options))
  .on('data', (data) => {
    // handle your logic
  })
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for bigger JSONs. What do you think could be the reason ?

Comment: Debugging streams can be very tricky, an interesting way is to see the node internals, run your application with NODE_DEBUG=stream node index.js and it will start the debug mode for node streams

Comment: I am getting 
STREAM 27397: ondata
STREAM 27397: read 0
STREAM 27397: need readable true
STREAM 27397: length less than watermark true
STREAM 27397: do read
STREAM 27397: emitReadable true
STREAM 27397: emit readable
STREAM 27397: flow true
STREAM 27397: read undefined
STREAM 27397: onend
STREAM 27397: onfinish
STREAM 27397: unpipe